# Vega-Lite: text stroke on the outside

Tags: json, charts, visualization, vega-lite

I have a [Vega-Lite bar chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ADU+-ADIiABKXURdZtgDMzTJOrOxnmM3fVsEZrLnwiNiYIOHViJCZBOBgAR0ooHwIAAWUAZgJo51l+dP5oJGiISkUQAHcaZXo0ABYABjqlZSRMFFRQCMEGNTQAbVBZJAQ4NBBAHg3AKX3SxIZZTDQAJgBGAF8FAaGR9DHAcX3ptln51CW0tY3h0bHAeX39w7QADjOQQYvtwBl927m0MSeXrfHAAr7nyOp3Wz02l0A0vvAxa-CHbQBy+zDjnDXuNAJL7yNWAF01iA4LJEsoaLIyGhQABPckgOw0OCCZSjP6lTAUnD-WQ+EmFUoydRHED8AAeLLo0TQsgYgkEeJF7RpdIZoxmXyUrPZo1iDCQczoLRopFFmHFqEl0pWeMESApYT6oGQ6gA1qMnOpSgSiSSyfLEoI2G75bT6Yz0Cr5mq2f8tTqdK0dIa1WL-gA5BgIJhhWwOLwMOggC1PB3O+Xq-6YOBC8MgQo0Mh6ECaMhYUpCgDydjsoSO-BqSmcNDadkKoSUtOlLqtUGdSggmG8jv+ZRgIlKdjkmAAyjQAF5bJYLGdztgLgDqlWqKKUHrYxNJ1PLlepQaVoYOqpApc12t1cYNIwLuJAA) with data labels on the bars. The issue is when the colors are dynamic, the text becomes low-contrast and unreadable. I would like to add a white outline to the text. However, if I just set "stroke": "white" to the text mark, the stroke overlaps the font and makes it look glitchy:

[image]

I want the stroke to be only on the outside of the text fill. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better technique is to look at the luminance as described here: https://github.com/Giammaria/Vega-Lite-Techniques?tab=readme-ov-file#luminance-to-determine-font-color

If you want to use a stroke, then this gets you close.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Vega-Lite bar chart from https://observablehq.com/@d3/learn-d3-scales.",
  "width": 400,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"name": "", "count": 21},
      {"name": "", "count": 13},
      {"name": "", "count": 8},
      {"name": "", "count": 5},
      {"name": "", "count": 3},
      {"name": "", "count": 2},
      {"name": "", "count": 1},
      {"name": "", "count": 1}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal", "sort": "-x", "title": null},
    "x": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative", "title": null}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "count",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Number of fruit"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "right",
        "xOffset": -4,
        "aria": false,
        "fill": "transparent",
        "stroke": "white",
        "fontSize": 12,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "strokeWidth": 1.5
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "right",
        "xOffset": -4,
        "aria": false,
        "fill": "black",
        "fontSize": 12
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ok so the solution is to add 2 text layers – got it. Thought I was hoping for a less of a workaround, but I guess there is none.